# Determining when a repository was added to yum?

Tags: centos, yum

I'm on CentOS 6.6.  Is there a way to determine when a repository was added to the list of repositories searched by yum?

```
yum repolist -v
```

Returns when the repos were last updated, but not when they were enabled.

Comment: You can try to infer this information by viewing the yum logs: `sudo grep '<reponame>' /var/log/yum.log` but enables/disables may not be logged at all with the `yum --enablerepo` and `yum-config-manager` commands. I tested these two commands, enabling and disabling a given repo on my centos machine and couldn't find anything within any logs. Enable/disable dates aren't visible either with `yum repolist` nor with `repoquery`. :/

Comment: The closest thing I got was checking the time stamps in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`.  It is unclear if the time stamps get modified during a repo related update.